# Skype stuck on "Signing in" window

Tags: macos, skype

After upgrading OSX to Yosemite and Skype to 7.7 (335), Skype gets stuck on "Signing in..." when starting.

It does sign in, as <kbd>Contacts > Add Contact</kbd> forces the main window to open, but "Signing in..." never goes away.

Already tried, but didn't work:

- Signing out, quitting ("Signing in..." stays even when signed out), then signing back in.
- Everything on the Skype support page for [Why can't I sign in to Skype for Mac OS X?](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA10038/why-can-t-i-sign-in-to-skype-for-mac-os-x).
- Removing `~/Library/Application Support/Skype`.
- Reinstalling Skype

I'm using my Microsoft ID to sign in.

Any clues?

---

Following the @Buscar advice I used `nettop` in terminal to monitor Skype connections.

After quitting Skype, I see 3 connections still there about 20 seconds after quitting. Two of them use port 443 (status LastAck and FinWait1), the other is on a high port (12k+), status FinWait1. Last one to go away is to blu403-m.hotmail.com:443 with status FinWait1.

Answer (score 2):

The following procedure seems to have solved the problem:

1. Sign out from Skype
2. Quit Skype and wait until all connections listed in `nettop` are cleared
3. Open Skype
4. Choose "Sign in with a different account" from the Microsoft ID login screen.
5. Try to sign in with Skype Name (but fail, since I can't do that anymore after I linked my Skype account to my MS account).
6. Go back and sign in with my Microsoft ID.

The "Signing in..." window was displayed for a few seconds, then the home window opened normally. Problem solved. I'm guessing steps 4-6 solved the issue, but I have no idea why.

Comment: That is good enough for me a +

Answer (score 2):

At some point skype on my office mac was unable to connect.
After trying all the mentioned solutions (update, re-install, delete all preferences files) the problem was still there.
On other PC/Mac/Phone I was able to connect.

After some investigation I found that on my office mac I had a public IP address and a secondary private IP address (non routable; like 10.xx.xx.xx) for internal use. Looking at the skype network activity I discovered it used both address.

**After disabling the private address it started to work again.**

Beware: if you are connected to internet through a modem router (wifi or cabled) your router is doing NAT and so you have a private address that is routed to the public network and so your case is different from mine.

PS Solved the connection problem, if I re-enable the private address, skype is able to work and even to login. *Really a nice piece of software!*

Comment: `ifconfig` to show the IP addresses that you have, then something like `sudo ifconfig en0 delete 10.0.0.1` to delete the one that is wrong.  I had a bad address from a previous VPN connection, and as soon as I deleted it, Skype could connect again.

Comment: Voting this answer up. I had the same problem and I fixed it by disabling a secondary IP address I had on the same network interface. On OSX it's called Virtual Interface. After that Skype could log in normally

Answer (score 0):

1. Kill Skype
2. Open **~/Library/Application Support/Microsoft** folder
3. Move **Skype for Desktop** folder to trash
4. Restart Skype